# sql how can I replace 'x' with ' X '?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

There is Ebat column

```
80x150
100x150
200x200


UPDATE table SET Ebat = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Ebat, 1, 3), ' ', 'X', ' ', SUBSTRING(Ebat,5,7));
```

this query finish

finish error write

```
80x X 00
100 x 150
200 X 200
```

that is true:

```
80 X 150
100 X 150
200 X 200
```

why can ı write code true?

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't `replace()` be much easier?

```
update t
    set ebat = replace(ebat, 'x', ' X ');
```

The problem with your version is that the part before the `x` varies in position.  It is not always at character position 4.  You are not taking that into account.